# Where do I put a certain alias to always work in a terminal in MAC?

Tags: mac, unix, terminal

On my **linux system** (ubuntu), when I create a certain alias in `~/.bashrc` and then restart the terminal/system, the alias always works again, without reloading anything.

But on my **MAC system**, when I create the same alias in the same file, it only works in the current terminal session, but not anymore after restarting the terminal. I need to do `source ~/.bashrc` to get it loaded again.

Question: How/where do I create the alias in my MAC system so that it always works, without reloading anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Depending on how the terminal is launched, it will run either `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

If you want the alias to be available everywhere it needs to run with the login terminal which loads the profile.